# Find a representative submatrix

Tags: code-golf, math, geometry

You have a matrix of size *m* x *n*.

Each cell in the matrix has a uniformly random integer value *v*, where 0 ≤ *v* < *i*, and *i* ≤ (*m* x *n*). (Meaning, the matrix contains a maximum of *m* x *n* distinct values, but it may have fewer.)

1) Write a function that accepts input values of *m*, *n*, *i*, and returns a matrix that meets the criteria above.

2) Write a second function that accepts the output of the first function as input, and returns the smallest [contiguous submatrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Submatrix.html) that contains every value of *v* (by returning the submatrix itself, or its coordinates). By “smallest” I mean the submatrix containing the fewest cells.

(If it helps you visualize, the original inspiration for this problem was wondering how to find the smallest rectangle within a GIF that contained all the colors in its palette.)

Comment: This needs some clarification about the randomness. Clearly the random variables aren't independent, because that would conflict with the requirement that every possible value of *v* appear at least once. So what are the permitted distributions?

Comment: @PeterTaylor: As I understand it, you could for example first place the values from 0 to *i*−1 randomly on the matrix, then fill up the remaining elements with random numbers from 0 to *i*−1. (Or anything that produces the same distribution of matrices.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, probably. But could you also just make all the matrices generated by your program be permutations of the first *mn* characters from an infinite sequence which just repeats *0* to *i*?

Comment: @weston When `i = mn`, the second part of the question is trivial, so `i ≤ mn` is deliberate.

Comment: Smallest submatrix regarding which metric? Product of dimensions?

Comment: OK, I’ve simplified it. Each cell gets a random integer in the range `0 .. i-1`. So over repeated trials, we would expect the occurrence of each value to converge on `mn / i`, just like repeated coin flips or die rolls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### APL (23 + 56 = 79)

#### Function 1 (23):

```
{¯1+⍵⍴(V⍴⍺?⍺)[V?V←×/⍵]}
```

This takes `i` as its left argument and `m n` as its right argument, like so:

```
      +mat←8 {¯1+⍵⍴(V⍴⍺?⍺)[V?V←×/⍵]} 5 5
2 4 7 1 3
7 5 6 7 3
3 1 2 4 6
0 4 2 6 1
5 5 0 0 6
```

#### Function 2 (56):

```
{⊃V[⍋≢∘∊¨V←V/⍨{∧/⍵∊⍨∪∊M}¨V←⊃,/{↓∘⍵¨¯1+,⍳⍴⍵}¨↑∘⍵¨,⍳⍴M←⍵]}
```

This takes the output from the first function as its right argument, like so:

```
      {⊃V[⍋≢∘∊¨V←V/⍨{∧/⍵∊⍨∪∊M}¨V←⊃,/{↓∘⍵¨¯1+,⍳⍴⍵}¨↑∘⍵¨,⍳⍴M←⍵]} mat
7 5 6
3 1 2
0 4 2
```

Comment: This makes me want to learn APL.